# How to get twitter profile pics URL in iOS now?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, xcode4.5

I used to do this:

```
NSString * strPictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=%@&size=bigger",strUsername.RobustURLEncodedString];
```

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=username&size=bigger

That no longer works anymore. Twitter turn off that API. Well, I am authenticated already. So how do I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new way of doing it

```
            NSDictionary * resp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&jsonError];


            self.strUsername  = [resp objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
            NSString * strPictureURL = [resp objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
            strPictureURL = [strPictureURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_normal" withString:@""];
            self.strPictureURL = strPictureURL;
```

Comment: Working perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Fabric Twitter library](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/introduction.html).

[Configuration](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/twitterkit-setup.html) is very easy:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"_key_" consumerSecret:@"_secret_"];
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]];
```

After it just use:

```
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
        NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
        TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
        [client loadUserWithID:userID completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Profile image url = %@", user.profileImageLargeURL);
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
NSString * strPictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_image?screen_name=%@&size=bigger",strUsername.RobustURLEncodedString];
```

instead of Version 1 , use version 1.1

Comment: that code https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_image?screen_name=teguh123&size=bigger doesn't work.